# VBA: Store ODBC query result in code, rather than displaying it

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I have the following macro, which accepts a string argument `code` which is a SQL query, and executes it against my Teradata server and displays the results.

```vb
Dim dest As Range
Set dest = ActiveCell

Dim timestamp As String
timestamp = Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd_h:mm:ss_AM/PM")

Dim queryName As String
queryName = "Query_" & timestamp

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=queryName, formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " Source = Odbc.Query(""dsn=my-server-name"", " _
    & Chr(34) & code & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) _
    & "" & Chr(10) & " Source"

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" _
    & queryName & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range(dest.Address)).QueryTable

    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & queryName & "]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

For one report I'm trying to automate, the first step is to query a particular timestamp from the database and make sure it shows today's date before proceeding with the rest of the report. I want to have a macro do that, but have it just *return* the timestamp value rather than *displaying* it-- that way I can write it into an If statement to conditionally run the next steps of the report.

Is there a way it can execute the query and store the returned timestamp in a variable rather than displaying it anywhere? Otherwise, I guess I'll just display it somewhere, interrogate the value and then delete it because I don't need it displayed.

Comment: You can get a lot more control over your queries if you switch to using ADO in place of querytables.  Plenty of examples here on SO and out on Google.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, I'll look into it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

### ADODB Solution

To get data from a query into a variable I would use an ADODB connection and recordset. Recordsets have a method called **GetRows** which returns the data from the query results.

Below is a function that can be used to query for your data. This takes in your **ConnectionString** and your **SQL Code** and returns your data in the form of a two-dimensional array.

> For ease of explaining, I made this function late binding. To make Early binding set a reference to the **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library**.

```vb
Private Function QueryDatabase(ByVal ConnectionString As String, ByVal Sql As String) As Variant
    
    On Error GoTo Catch
    
  
    'OPEN CONNECTION TO DATABASE
    Dim Connection As Object
    Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    Connection.Open
    On Error GoTo CloseConnection 'MAKE SURE TO CLOSE CONNECTION ON ERRORS
    
    'OPEN DATA AND GET RECORDSET
    Dim Rs As Object
    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With Rs
        .ActiveConnection = Connection
        .Source = Sql
        .LockType = 1 'adLockReadOnly - MAKES CONNECTION READ ONLY
        .CursorType = 0 'adOpenForwardOnly - FREQUENCY OF CHECKING DATABASE - SET TO ONCE
        .Open
        On Error GoTo CloseRecordset
    End With
    
    'RETURN QUERY RESULTS BACK INTO A TWO DIM ARRAY (DOES NOT INCLUDE HEADERS)
    QueryDatabase = Rs.GetRows
    
CloseRecordset:
    Rs.Close
    
CloseConnection:
    Connection.Close
    
    'CHECK IF ERROR OCCURED
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        GoTo Catch
    End If
    
    Exit Function
Catch:
    'HANDLE ERRORS HERE...
    
End Function
```

---

### Timestamp Validation

For validating your timestamp I would abstract that into its own formula returning a boolean value. Not exactly sure how your data is structured, or how you want to achieve this but below is a blueprint of what you could attempt to do.

```vb
Private Function TimestampValid() As Boolean
    
    Dim QueryName As String
    QueryName = "Query_" & timestamp
    
    Dim Connection As String
    Connection = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & QueryName & ";Extended Properties="""""
    
    Dim Sql As String
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & QueryName & "]"
    
    'DATA IS A TWO DIM ARRAY (MINUS THE HEADERS)
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = QueryDatabase(Connection, Sql)
    
    'DO YOUR VALIDATION HERE...
    '(NOT SURE WHAT YOU ARE RETURNING SO I CAN'T DO IT FOR YOU)...
    
End Function
```